# Find all factorizations of a number

Tags: c++, algorithm, factorization

For example, 16 can be expressed in these ways:
2*2*2*2
4*2*2
4*4
8*2
(excluding the trivial case 1*16)

36:
2*2*3*3
2*2*9
2*18
4*3*3
12*3
4*9

Therefore, I need to find all the representations of any given number just like above.
To start, I was able to come up with all the divisors of a given number with the codes below:

```
void FindDivisors(int n)
{
    vector<int> my_vector;
    for (int i = 2; i < n/2 + 1; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
            my_vector.push_back(i); //store divisors in a vector.
    }
}
```

After this, I got stuck. How do I get from all the divisors to all the factorizations wanted?
I can think of a recursion method that seems to work but do not exactly know how to implement it:

Take 16 as the example. Let's name the function to find all the representations of n to be "Factor(n)". All non-trivial divisors of 16 are {2,4,8}. We divide 16 by each of its divisor and get {8, 4, 2}. Then Factor(16) = the union of 2*Factor(8), 4*Factor(4) and 8*Factor(8). However, this is as far as I got. I am new to recursion and not sure if this route works out. I need some help on how to put things together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you don't know the number of factors, the most effective solution is recursion.

You will need a vector to store the current path:

```
vector<int> path; // it will store all current factors
```

and a recursive function.
For every iteration you try to divide current remainder and remember:

```
void OutputRec(int value)
{
    if (value == 1) // We have divided the whole number
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++) cout << path[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;
        return;
    }

    for (int i = value; i > 1; i--)
    {
        if (value % i == 0) { // if it is divisible
            path.push_back(i); // add to path
            OutputRec(i, value / i); // continue working
            path.pop_back(); // remove from path
        }
    }
}

void Output(int value)
{
    cout << "Result for " << value << ": " << endl;
    path = vector<int>();
    OutputRec(value);
}

int main() {
    Output(4);
    Output(16);
    Output(36);
    Output(256);

    return 0;
}
```

For example, let we have 8. Here is how it works:

```
OutputRec(8), path = []:
    i = 8: divisible (8 / 1 = 1)
        OutputRec(1), path = [8], value == 1 > output "8".
    i = 7, 6, 5: not divisible
    i = 4: divisible (8 / 4 = 2)
        OutputRec(2), path = [4]:
            i2 = 2: divisible (2 / 2 = 1)
                OutputRec(1), path = [4 2], value == 1 > output "4 2".
    i = 3: not divisible
    i = 2: divisible (8 / 2 = 4)
        OutputRec(4), path = [2]:
            i3 = 4: divisible (4 / 4 = 1)
                OutputRec(1), path = [2 4], value == 1 > output "2 4".
            i3 = 3: not divisible
            i3 = 2: divisible (4 / 2 = 2)
                OutputRec(2), path = [2 2]:
                    i4 = 2: divisible (2 / 2 = 1)
                        OutputRec(1), path = [2 2 2], value == 1 > output "2 2 2"
```

**Result:

  8,

  4 * 2,

  2 * 4,

  2 * 2 * 2**

Now, you see the problem: [2 4] and [4 2] is duplicated answer. How can we avoid duplicating answers? The easiest approach is to output values only in ascending (descending, does not matter) order.

Let's add `max` variable and store the last number inserted into a path and find only those dividers which are less or equal to it. 
For example, if current path is [2], then the recursion shouldn't go for [2 4], but should go for [2 2]. The initial value of `max` is equal to `value` as the first number in the path can be any.

```
void OutputRec(int max, int value)
{
    if (value == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++) cout << path[i] << " ";
        if (path.size() == 1) cout << "1";
        cout << endl;
        return;
    }

    for (int i = max; i > 1; i--) // loop from max. Min(max, value) would be better
    {
        if (value % i == 0) {
            path.push_back(i);
            OutputRec(i, value / i);
            path.pop_back();
        }
    }
}

void Output(int value)
{
    cout << "Result for " << value << ": " << endl;
    path = vector<int>();
    OutputRec(value, value);
}
```

Here is how it works now:

```
OutputRec(8), path = []:
    i = 8: divisible (8 / 8 = 1)
        OutputRec(1), path = [8], value == 1 > output "8".
    i = 7, 6, 5: not divisible
    i = 4: divisible (8 / 4 = 2)
        OutputRec(2), path = [4]:
            i2 = 2: divisible
                OutputRec(1), path = [4 2], value == 1 > output "4 2".
    i = 3: not divisible
    i = 2: divisible (8 / 2 = 4)
        OutputRec(4), path = [2]:
            // notice i3 starts from 2, because last inserted is 2
            i3 = 2: divisible (4 / 2 = 2)
                OutputRec(2), path = [2 2]:
                    i4 = 2: divisible (2 / 2 = 1)
                        OutputRec(1), path = [2 2 2], value == 1 > output "2 2 2"
```

**Result:

  8,

  4 * 2,

  2 * 2 * 2**

Everything works fine! The only thing which looks incorrect is "8". It probably should be "8 * 1". You can add a line like `if (path.size() == 1) cout << "1";` to the output.

**Result:

  8 * 1,

  4 * 2,

  2 * 2 * 2**

**Here is the [working Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/f7salt).**

I hope that I didn't confuse you even more. It is really difficult to explain what recursion is at the first time. 
Recursion is like swimming or cycling - it looks difficult first. Then, you try it and learn it, and once you understand it - you will wonder why couldn't you do this before :) Good luck.

Comment: The incorrect `4` should bother you a little more than that. `4*1` still is not equals `8`.

Comment: @skyking Thanks! Just made an error once, and then copy-pasted it. Fixed it. Code still gives the correct result :)